# Find all zip files created today in a directory and its sub directories based on a pattern

Tags: files, find, wildcards, zip

I have multiple zip files in a directory and its sub directories with the pattern  ACCT_DOC. 
example 
T.6593.ACCT_DOC.1054.1_0.20170220.111425.zip
T.12561.ACCT_DOC.1003.1_0.20160121.221947.zip

I need a list of all the files matching the pattern *ACCT_DOC* that were created today. The YYYYMMDD is part of the file naming convention

i tried using find .  -type f -name '*ACCT_DOC.`date '+%Y%m%d'`*.zip' but it is  not working. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command should do the trick:

`find . -type f -name "*.ACCT_DOC.*.zip" -mmin -$(($(($(date +%H) * 60)) + $(date +%M)))`

From [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> -mmin n
>       File's data was last modified n minutes ago.

This output contains the whole path. If you want the basename of the file, simply pipe the resultset to awk:

`find . -type f -name "*.ACCT_DOC.*.zip" -mmin -$(($(($(date +%H) * 60)) + $(date +%M))) \
| awk -F"/" '{ print $NF }'`

`$NF` prints out the last element of the splitted path.

Comment: Worked great. Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was what you are looking for.

Comment: The result set also has the directory path included like ./SUPLR_SPND_CHINA/eff/LDI_SS_CHINASAP/ACCT_DOC/ARCHIVE/T.6593.ACCT_DOC.1054.1_0.20170220.111425.zip. I need only the list of zip files

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: -mmin -$(($(($(date +%H) * 60)) + $(date +%M))) , does this only select the files with today's date? . I have 2 files with today's Time Stamp but the result only had 1.

Comment: This calculates the current hours * 60 + current minutes. So it calculates back to 00:00. Furthermore find looks up the last edited value in the inode. Please determine with `ls -la` if the .zip was actually created today.